# optgroup left margin for some fonts in select dropdwon

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, optgroup

I am using following code to select font for font family.

But some fonts option get extra padding from left in select option. (please see below images)

code :

```
<select name="field_font" class="form-control ">
    <optgroup style="font-family:arial">
           <option value='Arial' {% if field_font== 'Arial' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Arial [1,2,3,4,5]</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup style="font-family:Arial Narrow">
           <option value='Arial Narrow' {% if field_font== 'Arial Narrow' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Arial Narrow [1,2,3,4,5]</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup style="font-family:Brush Script MT">
           <option value='Brush Script MT' {% if field_font== 'Brush Script MT' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Brush Script MT [1,2,3,4,5]</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup style="font-family:Calibri">
           <option value='Calibri' {% if field_font== 'Calibri' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Calibri [1,2,3,4,5]</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup style="font-family:Candara">
           <option value='Candara' {% if field_font== 'Candara' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Candara [1,2,3,4,5]</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup style="font-family:Courier New">
           <option value='Courier New' {% if field_font== 'Courier New' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Courier New [1,2,3,4,5]</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup style="font-family:Didot">
           <option value='Didot' {% if field_font== 'Didot' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Didot [1,2,3,4,5]</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup style="font-family:Garamond">
           <option value='Garamond' {% if field_font== 'Garamond' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Garamond [1,2,3,4,5]</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup style="font-family:Geneva">
           <option value='Geneva' {% if field_font== 'Geneva' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Geneva [1,2,3,4,5]</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup style="font-family:Helvetica">
           <option value='Helvetica' {% if field_font== 'Helvetica' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Helvetica [1,2,3,4,5]</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup style="font-family:Monaco">
           <option value='Monaco' {% if field_font== 'Monaco' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Monaco [1,2,3,4,5]</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup style="font-family:Open Sans, sans-serif">
           <option value='Open Sans, sans-serif' {% if field_font== 'Open Sans, sans-serif' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Open Sans, sans-serif [1,2,3,4,5] [Opencart Default]</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup style="font-family:Optima">
           <option value='Optima' {% if field_font== 'Optima' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Optima [1,2,3,4,5]</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup style="font-family:Times New Roman">
           <option value='Times New Roman' {% if field_font== 'Times New Roman' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Times New Roman [1,2,3,4,5]</option>
    </optgroup>                                                 
    <optgroup style="font-family:Verdana">
           <option value='Verdana' {% if field_font== 'Verdana' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Verdana [1,2,3,4,5]</option>
    </optgroup>             
 </select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's working as intended. The spacing that you see there is because each font has different letter spacing, line height etc.

The `Open Sans` font also has a bit of padding too, but not so much as Verdana and Courier.